# CI Pagination not work properly?

Tags: php, continuous-integration

Controller:

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->library("pagination");

//$this->load->library('result/Apache/Solr/apache_solr_service');       

       $this->load->library('email');
    }


public function index()
    {

        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/index/index";
        //print_r($config["base_url"]);
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->user_model->record_count();
        $limit = $config["per_page"] = 9;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
        //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $data['count']= $this->user_model->record_count();
        //print_r($data['count']);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $start = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
        $data["data"] = $this->user_model->product($limit,$start);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        print_r($data['links']);

 print_r($data['data']);

        //$this->load->view("pagination", $data);

        //$this->load->view('inc/header');  

        //$data['data']=$this->user_model->product();

        //$this->load->view('index',$data);

        //$this->load->view('inc/footer');
    }
```

Model:

```
public function product($limit, $start)
    {    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->order_by("id", "asc");

        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

        $query=$this->db->get('newdeal');

        return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

Comment: Just as a side note, you can load all them loaders in autoload so they don't need to be included at top of every controller.

Comment: Nouphal.M i am try to this  $config["uri_segment"] = 3; but value remaing same not change

Answer (score 0):

As Nouphal.M suggested in comments, change

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
```

to

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Also, as a side note, you can autoload your helpers/libraries by putting them in

```
application > config > autoload.php
```

Then put the libraries/helpers in the right arrays. e.g

```
$data['helper'] = array("url", "email", "form");
```